# Simulator is slow in Xcode 12.4

Tags: ios, react-native, simulator

After upgrading my Mac to Big Sur 11.2 and Xcode to 12.4 , I noticed that the simulator is running very slowly. it can take more than 5 seconds to execute a single command.
I've looked up a couple of solutions but nothing worked for me. my 'Slow animations' is not checked.
also running the images on a low quality is not a good option.
The simulator was working fine before the upgrade and nothing changed in my code.
I'm running iPhone 11 iOS 14.4 simulator.

Comment: did you try another iPhone or iOS version  ?

Comment: I'm experiencing this too. See: https://mjtsai.com/blog/2021/06/02/slow-testing-with-xcode-12-5-and-big-sur/

Comment: thanks James, the problem was eventually fixed on its own thankfully

Comment: What do you mean, fixed on its own? It may help me to know what fixed it.